# PHP system("touch ...") - no such file or directory

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have a basic PHP script like this:

```
<?php
system("/bin/touch /root/testfile");
```

When I run this PHP script from the command line:

```
# php myscript.php
```

I get this:

```
sh: /touch: No such file or directory
```

Also, touch is in the right place:

```
# which touch
/bin/touch
```

Is there something I need to setup in my PHP script regarding paths? Because it can't find touch (even though I specifically call it with its absolute path).

**UPDATE**

Running `/bin/touch /root/testfile` from the command line works properly as expected.

Also, `touch` isn't working, yes, but other things are not working as well, such as `sendmail`. I'm simply using `touch` as an example in this question to keep it simple.

Comment: What happens if you interactively run the `/bin/touch /root/testfile` command?

Comment: Why not use the [PHP touch](http://us3.php.net/touch)

Comment: What's the output of `system("/bin/pwd");` ?  If it's a similar error, then you've probably got safe_mode turned on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The PHP safe_mode is probably enable. You have to turn it off in your /etc/php.ini file.

Comment: Ah yes it is on. Is it safe to turn this off?

Comment: @Jakobud - probably not :)  Do you really need to do this?

Comment: @Jakobud: No it is not safe. And you should not `/bin/touch /root/testfile` from the very first time.

Comment: It depends by different things, but: 1) debian turn it off by default 2) I have it OFF on all of my prod servers.

Comment: @Jakobud - Rather than asking if it's safe to turn it off (which we can't possibly tell you), why don't you describe the problem you're trying to solve?  That would make for a good StackOverflow question!

Comment: The server is only used to send some emails via PHP (via some cronjobs). There is no internet-accessible web server running. So I'm going to assume it's safe to turn off. @bsdnoobz Can you explain why I shouldn't do that?

Comment: @Jakobud Actually its just a rule of thumb: don't `touch` the root.

Comment: Ah yeah well it was just an example. Could have been `/tmp/whatever`.